# Displaying Modified and Size in Contents panel of ArcMap's Catalog Window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, catalog-window

In ArcCatalog 10.0 SP2 it is possible to display the Modified and Size column values, and to sort by them.

However, in the Catalog window of ArcMap 10.0 SP2, it does not seem to be possible to do this.

The reason I am looking for this behaviour is that I have a large number of MXD files in a folder and want to be able to use the Catalog window to locate, and switch between, any of the last 10-12 that have been modified.  Without being able to sort them based on the Modified column (because it is not visible there), it is very cumbersome to scroll through them.

If this functionality is already present can somebody point me at where to find it, please?

Please note that using the Recent maps list is of no use for this because the maps I want to access have been created by a Python script and not previously opened in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [existing ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000btfb) for something very similar to this but it has a status of Implemented.  However, I think that is because it can be done in ArcCatalog and where I want the convenience of it being available is in the Catalog window.

After blah's comment I went ahead and posted a [new ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000c1DuAAI) (please vote).

Comment: I would suggest creating your own ArcGIS Idea specific to the ArcMap Catalog window. I am sure they thought of it when they were designing it, but just didn't get around to it or think anyone would use it. Remember the Catalog Window is new in 10 while ArcCatalog has been around for over a decade.