# Using ArcCatalog in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arccatalog, catalog-window

I have heard that using ArcMap can replace some functions of ArcCatalog.

If it is true, how is the process done in ArcCatalog?

I don't have access to ArcCatalog all the time. I can't spend all my time in a computer lab just for ArcCatalog. I have access to ArcMap at all times.

Answer (score 4):

To use "ArcCatalog" inside ArcMap you use the Catalog window.

Both the Catalog window and ArcCatalog are described in the help under [What is the Catalog window?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/what-is-the-catalog-window-.htm):

> In addition to the Catalog window in ArcMap, ArcGlobe, and ArcScene,
>   there is a stand-alone application named ArcCatalog that can be used
>   as an alternative for managing workspaces, geodatabases, GIS web
>   services, and ArcGIS Online.

For ArcGIS users I think there is very rarely a need to open ArcCatalog.  One example was and may still be [Displaying Modified and Size in Contents panel of ArcMap's Catalog Window?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24631/is-it-possible-to-display-modified-and-size-in-contents-panel-of-arcmaps-catalo) [I have not yet tested at ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop].

However, for ArcGIS administrators ArcCatalog remains popular, mainly I think, because it is quicker to open than ArcMap, and they rarely need to make a map.